# on click remove parent div

Tags: jquery, html

i am trying to remove a div on click on a link . the problem is there are multiple structure of same div and link and i tried making a function but it removes all div's

```js
$(document).on("click", ".fd-bxx-cls", function(e) {
  e.preventdefault;
  $(this).parents('.fd-box2').fadeOut(300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fd-box2">
  <div class="fd-box3">
    <a href="#" class="fd-bxx-cls"></a>
    <a class="fd-avtar-s" href="#"><img src="images/avatr_s.png" /></a>
    <div class="fd-nme-info">
      <span class="fd-mn-ttl">Robert Porter</span>
      <span class="fd-mncn-ttl">Pheonix, AZ</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="ep-btns fd-msg-btn"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fading out the grandparent should work.

```
$(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(300);
```

Another possibility is using [`.closest()`](http://api.jQuery.com/closest/).

```
$(this).closest(".fd-box2").fadeOut(300);
```

Comment: And this is inherently tied to the DOM structure. Use [`closest()`](http://api.jQuery.com/closest/) with an appropriate selector, and save yourself the need to learn exactly how many levels of nesting exists between the two objects/nodes.

Comment: @DavidThomas, you're right, I edited the answer to reflect your comment

Comment: @Alexander i tried `closest` before too it didnt worked but ur parent and parent worked like a charm . Thanks you so much lot for helping

Comment: i just found that it only works for 2nd set of same structure and so on , but not for first

Comment: @ParamVeer, it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BZ6nJ/). You may want to update your code then, it may not reflect the reality

Comment: @Param: could you show your `closest()`-based attempt(s)? We may be able to offer advice (because it *should* work...).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method instead of [**parents()**](http://api.jquery.com/parents/). See the difference in documentation.

Also if you want to **REMOVE** an element (and not just hide it) use [**remove()**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method.