# .Remove() removes all div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am working on an php page that adds an li element on button click that is sortable due to jquery. What I am having an issue with is closing/removing that li element. Below is what I am using:

What is occurring is all the li elements are removed from the page and all I would like is the parent li to be removed.

I have checked around but couldn't find anything to resolve the issue.

[Jquery Remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996961/on-click-remove-parent-div) | [Delete Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647736/how-to-delete-parent-element-using-jquery) | [Remove Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942294/remove-parent-div)

I believe this has to do with my jquery but I can't find out where.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#sortable").append('<li class="ui-state-default"><div id="menu" style="position: relative; margin-top:3px; font-size:25px; width:100%; height:30px;"><a id="close" href="" class="close">x</a><div id="box-name">Test 1</div></div></div></li>');
  });
});
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
  $(this).parent('.ui-state-default').remove();
  //$(this).closest('.ui-state-default').fadeOut(300);
});
```

```css
#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
}
#sortable li {
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  width: 23.00%;
  height: 97.5%;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px .5px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<script>
</script>

<body>
  <div id="">
    <!-- button to add li -->
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Click me">
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    <!-- Container div -->
    <ul id="sortable">
      <!-- beginning of sortable list -->

      <li class="ui-state-default">
        <!-- li class that is duplicated -->
        <div id="menu" style="position: relative; margin-top:3px; font-size:25px; width:100%; height:30px;">
          <a class="close" id="close" href="">
            <!-- a tag to close li -->
            x
          </a>
          <div id="box-name">Test 1</div>
        </div>
  </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see where you are doing any removing at all. Are you showing that code here?

Comment: @Matt Spinks I had the .remove commented out as I experimented with other jquery . options. Post has been edited to reflect .remove.

Comment: you call jquery two times and calls to scripts are above doctype declaration, also you have one extra div in your html. it should be fixed

Comment: From your script and markup, I can see that all you li have the class `ui-state-default`. You need to use your jquery target the specific li you want to action on. Example is using `$(this)` - It will only action on the clicked li.

Comment: @Peter  $(this).remove(); does the same thing. It deletes every li created and not a single instance or parent li.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event listener actually isn't being called because you are navigating away from the initial page. When you click on the anchor element, the `href` is blank, which redirects you to a blank page. Therefore the elements aren't all being removed, you are actually just looking at a blank page.

You could change the `href` attributes to `href="#"` in order to mitigate this.

You can also call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent this default behavior:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(this).closest('.ui-state-default').fadeOut(300);
});
```

In addition, you also need to change `id="close"` to `class="close"` since that is what your jQuery selectors are targeting. It's also worth mentioning that `id`s must be unique. If you find yourself duplicating an `id`, just use a class instead.

Here is an updated example:

```js
$("#sortable").sortable();
$("#sortable").disableSelection();

$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#sortable").append('<li class="ui-state-default"><div id="menu" style="position: relative; margin-top:3px; font-size:25px; width:100%; height:30px;"><a class="close" href="#">x</a><div id="box-name">Test 1</div></div></div></li>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.close', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(this).closest('.ui-state-default').fadeOut(300);
});
```

```css
#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
}
#sortable li {
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  width: 23.00%;
  height: 97.5%;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px .5px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Click me">
</div>
<div class="data">
  <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">
      <div id="menu" style="position: relative; margin-top:3px; font-size:25px; width:100%; height:30px;">
        <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
        <div id="box-name">Test 1</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Using href="#" will not allow the jquery function to run. As does using event.preventDefault();.

Comment: @Inneshfree - Huh? Did you look at the example I posted?

Comment: I did but when I went to implement it into my main project it was coming up with an issue where the add button wouldn't work. I just rewrote my functions and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to this `$.fadeOut()` line, which will hide an element from the page (doesn't `$.remove()` it though)

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
    // $(this).parent('.ui-state-default').remove();
    $(this).closest('.ui-state-default').fadeOut(300);
});
```

In your jquery, you append this

```
    $("#sortable").append('<li class="ui-state-default"><div id="menu" style="position: relative; margin-top:3px; font-size:25px; width:100%; height:30px;"><a id="close" href="">x</a><div id="box-name">Test 1</div></div></div></li>');
```

But you hide elements via this click handler

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
```

Your click handler references `.close`, but in you jQuery append, you just add `#close`. So change the code in you jquery append from `<a id="close" href="">` to `<a id="close" href="" class="close">`. Here's that full line

```
$("#sortable").append('<li class="ui-state-default"><div id="menu" style="position: relative; margin-top:3px; font-size:25px; width:100%; height:30px;"><a id="close" href="" class="close">x</a><div id="box-name">Test 1</div></div></div></li>');
```

Comment: I adjusted as you suggested and it still clears out any li created and not a single instance of it.

Comment: @Inneshfree in your HTML, you misspelled `class` you have `<a clas="close" id="close" href="">` and it needs to be `<a class="close" id="close" href="">`. Also I don't see the `class` added to the jquery append line...

Comment: thanks for that catch. I added the class="close" to both locations and still have the same result.

Comment: @Inneshfree you still aren't updating your jquery append line.

Change this `$("#sortable").append('<li class="ui-state-default"><div id="menu" style="position: relative; margin-top:3px; font-size:25px; width:100%; height:30px;"><a id="close" href="">x</a><div id="box-name">Test 1</div></div></div></li>');`

to this `$("#sortable").append('<li class="ui-state-default"><div id="menu" style="position: relative; margin-top:3px; font-size:25px; width:100%; height:30px;"><a id="close" href="" class="close">x</a><div id="box-name">Test 1</div></div></div></li>');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery first or nth selector

https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

```
$( "ul li:first" )
```

https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
$( "ul li:nth-child(2)" )
```

Or combine them if needed

```
$( "ul:first li:nth-child(2)" )
```

Comment: I am needing a dynamic method to select a single instance/parent li. Using NTH seems to only delete what I set and won't work if I have 5 li's and only want to delete the 4th while my nth is set to (2).

Comment: var elementPlacement = 4; //The element you want to delete $( "ul li:nth-child("+elementPlacement+")");